# MySQL index for MIN and MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

Could anyone clarify this point from the official MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> Indexes are used ... To find the MIN() or MAX() value for a specific indexed column key_col. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you are using WHERE key_part_N = constant on all key parts that occur before key_col in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key lookup for each MIN() or MAX() expression and replaces it with a constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query returns at once. For example: *SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2) FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;*

So in their exampe they're trying to find the min and max values of the col called key_col. Are they using a composite index key_part1_key_part2? Does key_part2 part of the index represent key_col column?

I absolutely don't understand what they're trying to say of replacing the expressions by the constant. Could you help me to work out this point?

**UPDATE:** The question is not about how the `WHERE` statement or indexes work on the "highest levels", if I can say that. I was confused by this processor's expression replacing thing in this certain point about MIN and MAX.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(b), MAX(b) FROM tbl WHERE a = 12;
```

loves

```
INDEX(a, b)
```

both columns, in that order.

The query looks in the index for `a = 12`, grabs the first `(a,b)` pair to get `MIN(b)` and grabs the last pair to get `MAX(b)`.

The statement about "replacing with a constant" is confusing because it is going too deep into the details of how it first figures out how to perform the query (which happens to get the min and max), then proceeds to execute what is left of the query (nothing is left).

More generally, the optimal index is *usually* one that starts with all the `WHERE` columns compared to constants with `=`.  After that it gets complex, so let me give another tip:

A "covering" index is one that has all the columns mentioned in the `SELECT` (`a` and `b` in my example).

Sorry, I don't seem to be clearer than the manual.

Answer (score 1):

In their example they are not trying to find the min and max values of the column called key_col. They are trying to find the min and max of the second key in a multi-column key. The issue is further complicated since the query is limiting its search to the subset of the multi-column key set that is defined by having the key_part1 = 10.

```
10, 2, 3
10, 9, 5
10, 7, 7
10, 3, 1
10, 2, 5
11, 3, 0
11, 0, 3
```

So in this example the query selects only the rows where the first column is 10. Then it finds that among the rows with 10 in the first column the min for the second column is 2 and the max is 9. Notice that 0 in the second column is not chosen as the min because the first column does not match on 10. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man, it's pretty clear how the query basically works. I was confused by their explanation. So does the statement about the query's speed > "In this case, MySQL does a single key lookup ... If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query returns at once." simply means that if the first column has the same value=10 for all the rows of the table then the query is executed instantly? What if all the expressions are not replaced with the constant (10 in our case) - does it mean that there are some other values in the first column that are not satisfy the where statement?

Comment: @Sergey If the query had ended with `WHERE key_part1 = <expression>`, it can't find the first column in the index until it evaluates the expression.

Comment: @Barmar as per the their example, key_part1 = 10. This is a constant and there is nothing to evaluate/replace, the query is executed instantly. Are the things above the example that they are talking about related to expression evaluating in the WHERE statement in the case if they're not simple constants?

Comment: @Sergey Some of them are about evaluating the `WHERE` clause, some are about optimizing joins, some are about `ORDER BY`. Indexes have many uses.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I'm talking only about this certain min and max point and the preprocessor's expression replacing thing. It's slightly confusing, isn't it?

Comment: @Sergey Normally, the query planner figures out which indexes to use to help the query processor optimize the query. But in this particular case, the process of figuring this out can actually get the answer to the whole query, because all the information is in a single index entry.