# How does the indexing work to find MIN() or MAX() value for a specific indexed column and sort a table in following scenario?

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing, max, min

Following is the text from [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) :

> - To find the `MIN()` or `MAX()` value for a specific indexed column
>     ***key_col***. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you
>     are using WHERE ***key_part_N = constant*** on all key parts that occur
>     before ***key_col*** in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key
>     lookup for each `MIN()` or `MAX()` expression and replaces it with a
>     constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query
>     returns at once. For example:

```
SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2)
  FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;
```

> - To sort or group a table if the sorting or grouping is done on a
>     leftmost prefix of a usable index (for example, ORDER BY ***key_part1,
>     key_part2***). If all key parts are followed by `DESC`, the key is read in
>     reverse order.
> - In some cases, a query can be optimized to retrieve values without
>     consulting the data rows. (An index that provides all the necessary
>     results for a query is called a covering index.) If a query uses from
>     a table only columns that are included in some index, the selected
>     values can be retrieved from the index tree for greater speed:

```
SELECT key_part3 FROM tbl_name
  WHERE key_part1=1
```

I'm not at all able to understand these points and the respective code from the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Someone please make the things easy in order to clarify the things to make me understand.

**I am not asking what is Indexing and how does work, etc. etc.**

I just want to understand what these sentences are trying to say and what's happening out there in the code?

What are ***key_par_N*** and what's the purpose of using them here?

What does actually mean by the term key part in this context?

What does mean by all key parts that occur before ***key_col*** in the index?

Where is the column ***key_col*** of which we are supposed to fine `MIN()` and `MAX()` values (**See the first line :** To find the `MIN()` or `MAX()` value for a specific indexed column ***key_col***.)?

Someone please make me clear everything.

**Note : I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991550/mysql-index-for-min-and-max) question which is asking the same thing but it has received a generalized answer which is not specific to the explanation and code given in the manual. So, I'm asking this question to get precise and specific answer. So, please don't mark my question duplicate.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you can create an index in order to index multiple columns e.g., `create index idx on t1 (key_colX, key_colY)`. Now `key_part1 is key_colX` and `key_part2 is key_colY`. The order is important!

Let´s say we use a bTree as an index structure, then elements are organized according to key_part1 first, if key_part1 of two elements is equal then according to key_part2. Now if you issue a query and set key_part1 = 10 to a (constant) value, the DB can quickly find the subtree of the bTree where key_part1 = 10. All elements in this subtree are organized according to key_part2 which makes a Min() or Max() very efficient.

If you try the query the other way

```
SELECT MIN(key_part1),MAX(key_part1) FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part2=10;
```

then the index cannot be utilized.

So the above basically says you can answer queries more efficiently if your query can utilize the order of the indexed columns.

Comment: Thanks for the to the point answer. Just make me clear the sentence " All elements in this subtree are organized according to key_part2 which makes a Min() or Max() very efficient". In the whole answer I'm only not able to understand this single sentence. Please make me clear. Thanks once again. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @SerialKisser, after reading it again, that part of my description was a bit simplified and imprecise. Basically, what I wanted to say is that in a btree  which is organized by keys (key_part1, key_part2), you can search for a all elements where key_part1 = constant and it will give you the resulting elements ordered by key_part2.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a list of people names.  And you want to find the first and last (alphabetically) "Smith"  How would you do that on paper?  You would flip to the beginning of the Smiths to find Aaron, then flip to the end of the Smiths to find Ziggy.

What about a table with `INDEX(lastname, firstname)` and the SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(firstname), MAX(firstname)
    FROM names
    WHERE lastname = 'Smith';
```

It would work pretty much the same way.

(I find "lastname" more user-friendly than "key_part_1".)

Many Index issues can be deduced by thinking about how it would be done with paper or a Rolodex or a Library "card catalog" (if you are old enough to remember such).

My [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) does not happen to discuss that, but it provides other insights into indexing.

To generalize on the "key_part" and max and min...  If you can visualize flipping to a list of things and reaching to the first (for min) or last (for max), and it will be the 'right' answer, then the equivalent `INDEX` will *probably* work that way.

Here is a common place where max and min get tripped up.  Suppose some of the names are marked as "deleted" or "deceased" (or whatever), and you don't want them.  Now it is not as simple a finding the first and last Smith.  Rather you would need to go to the start and end and scan.  This is a case where the following code is *not* well optimized:

```
SELECT MIN(firstname), MAX(firstname)
    FROM names
    WHERE lastname = 'Smith'
      AND deleted = 0;     -- This is a monkey wrench
```

So, `INDEX(lastname, firstname)` will not help much.

OTOH, `INDEX(deleted, lastname, firstname)` will help.  However this is unrealistic for a paper list, and clumsy for a Rolodex.  For a paper list, you would be erasing names from where they are and moving them to the end of the list, which contains the deleted people.  With a Rolodex, you pull a card and move it to another spot.  Guess what -- that is what MySQL has to do in the index when you say

```
 UPDATE list
     SET deleted = 1
     WHERE lastname = 'Smith'
       AND firstname = 'John';
```